# How to craft a paper binding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I'm playing Agrarian Skies with a friend on a server I host myself, and we're starting to get the hang of Tinker's construct and its tools.

However we can't figure out how to craft paper bindings. It doesn't help that the tool station doesn't have any of its recipes show up in NEI, but there are only two kinds of paper (that I know of): paper and stack of paper, and neither of these work with the binding pattern.

Is this item disabled for this modpack, do I have mismatched item IDs, or am I using the wrong kind of paper?

Answer (score 2):

The Agrarian Skies default config file `IguanaTweaksTConstruct.cfg` is responsible for (dis)allowing paper tools.

[Speculation] I'm assuming paper parts were disabled to make early game tools harder to craft. However, the Writable attribute is super useful for making OP mid/late-game tools, especially as the binding.

```
# IguanaTweaksTConstruct.cfg:371-398
# Pattern ids to restrict for paper parts
I:restrictedPaperParts <
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
    21
    22
    23
    24
    25
 >
```

I'm not sure which number is the part binding. I'm just going to un-restrict all the paper parts for my server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  My assumption was that it was disabled in the mod pack, although I couldn't see why.  I just gave myself creative powers, placed a paper binding in my inventory and reverted back to survival, throwing a paper into the void as payment.

Comment: I figured that's what I'd have to end up doing, wish there was a way to get an overview of all the mods you have running and how they interact so you could see which mods might interfere unintentionally